# How to select a value from IOS spinner using java selenium and appium

Tags: java, ios, selenium, automation, appium

I am trying to select a value from an IOS drop-down element:

[image]

I am able to to that in Android, but can't find the right way to do that in IOS... 
Appreciates any help...

Here is how I do it in Android:

```
        driver.findElement(By.id("<#My element#>"))
              .click();
        List<WebElement> listsDropDown = driver.findElements(By.className("android.widget.TextView"));
        for (WebElement listdropdown : listsDropDown) {
            String list = listdropdown.getText();
            if (list.equals(<"#My text value#">)) {
                listdropdown.click();
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This link might be useful https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/UsingtheAutomationInstrument/UsingtheAutomationInstrument.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004652-CH20-SW85

Answer (score 0):

driver.scrollTo("text") should work.